# No se encuentra MainActivity.java en el proyecto

Tags: flutter, dart

Es un proyecto en Visual Studio Code, usando Flutter y Dart, se encuentra MainActivity.kt pero MainActivity.java no se encuentra, tras investigaciones se tiene que se puede crear la clase manualmente  y  el codigo es el siguiente pero que importaciones deberia tener?

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Emran, tiene usted una solucion?

Answer (score 0):

lo recomendable seria que uses MainActivity.kt
pero, respondiendo a tu pregunta estos serian los imports para .java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
```